# How to put the character & into an xml in android correctly

Tags: java, android

I have a string that says "the following characters are invalid: "! @ # $ % ^ \& * ( ) / \ or space" and i don't know how to put the & symbol into an xml file without causing an error? I know you are suppose to do something along the lines of \& but I'm not sure exactly what it is?

Comment: relevent: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091945/where-can-i-get-a-list-of-the-xml-document-escape-characters

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If `\&` doesn't work, try the XML entity `&amp;`.

Comment: thanks! I saw that before you said it but it didn't look right but its what i was looking for so thank you!

Comment: for '  = 'apos;

more from
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references

Answer (score 8):

& would be `&amp;`.

Wikipedia has [a list of XML and HTML character entity references](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references).

Answer (score 6):

in the context of an XML

```
& is &amp;
< is &lt;
> is &gt;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple. Use `&amp;`